# How to apply horizontal kerning to all letters in the word at once without adjusting the spacing for each letter?

Tags: text, inkscape, kerning

I am trying to increase the spacing between letters in a word in Inkscape (version 0.48) by using horizontal kerning. I am not able to select the entire word and apply the kerning value at once. I need to do it for each word in the letter. Is there a way to adjust the spacing for all the letters in the word at once?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adjusting letter spacing is called *tracking*. :) Hopefully this will help you find your answer if you ask elsewhere.

From the [Inkscape Forum](http://www.inkscapeforum.com/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=2216):

1. Switch to the Text tool.
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> to select all of the text.
3. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>></kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd><</kbd> to adjust the tracking.

If `<` requires a modifier for your keyboard layout, remember to press the modifier key as well.

To adjust the vertical spacing, perform the first two steps as above, but use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>></kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd><</kbd> instead.

Comment: @chanduc: You also should consider upvoting the answer in this case, if you haven’t done so yet.

Comment: Does this work in Inkscape 0.91? It seems to just change the size of the entire selected text object. Seems documentation is definitely lacking for newer versions.

Comment: Figured it out. Key phrase is "While in Text tool" though you don't have to select all the text.